# VBA to select columns with headers in excel (How to auto-fit columns with data?)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Using VBA how can I select all the columns with headers in Excel? or all the columns which are not blank? Basically select all the columns with data in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofit columns with data

```
Sub AutoFit()
    Rows("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Or possibly

```
Sub AutoFitCell()
  Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: That answer has nothing to do with the question!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use something like `range("A1").CurrentRegion`.
To address the columns: `range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns`.
About "selecting": this is generally useless and just slowing down your code. Never `Select` unless you have a serious justification for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this however selects the data but ow can I select the columns? I want to set the column width to autofit for all the columns with data. When I use Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select this selects only the cells and not whole columns

Comment: You should have asked "How to autofit columns with data"!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could be useful to you, but what if you were to select all the cells that have data in them? Here's a little Macro for you, just edit the ranges to match you criteria

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:G" & LR)
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cell
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    rng.Select
End With
End Sub
```